# MS sql server split value

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

Good day 
I stack with my code when i can not split value.

I would have :

```
    Table
    columnname
   John Ede 045332
    Eva Neo 154123
    Alex Bob 1489



  I need

    Table
    columnname           newcolumn   
    dddddjh hdgh         045332
    gdggeg dgdfg         154123
    gfdhfh hgfh          1489
```

I do :

```
ALTER Table 
add newcolumn varchar (50);

GO

insert into newcolumn 
Select [columnname]=right([columnname],len([columnname])-(charindex(' ',' ',[columnname])-1))
from[dbo].[table]
```

thank you for help me out from three parameters.

Comment: You should use `UPDATE` statement instead of `INSERT` in order to populate `newcolumn` with new values

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update existing rows, you should use an `update` statement, not an `insert` statement:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[table]
SET    newcolumn = RIGHT([columnname], LEN([columnname]) - (CHARINDEX(' ', ' ', [columnname])-1))
```

Comment: I did before this but same..Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Argument data type nvarchar is invalid for argument 3 of charindex function.

Answer (score 0):

I would use following approach:

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (
    Col1    VARCHAR(100),
    Col2    VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT  @Table1(Col1) VALUES ('dddddjh hdgh 045332 123');
INSERT  @Table1(Col1) VALUES ('dddddjh hdgh 045332');
INSERT  @Table1(Col1) VALUES ('gdggeg dgdfg 154123');
INSERT  @Table1(Col1) VALUES ('gdggeg dgdfg 1');
INSERT  @Table1(Col1) VALUES ('gdggeg dgdfg');
INSERT  @Table1(Col1) VALUES ('gdggeg ');
INSERT  @Table1(Col1) VALUES ('gdggeg');
INSERT  @Table1(Col1) VALUES (' ');
INSERT  @Table1(Col1) VALUES ('');
INSERT  @Table1(Col1) VALUES (NULL);

WITH CteUpdate
AS (
SELECT  t1.Col1, 
        t1.Col2,
        LeftPart    = LEFT(t1.Col1, ISNULL(NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', t1.Col1), 0) - 1, 8000)),
        RightPart   = SUBSTRING(t1.Col1, NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', t1.Col1), 0), 8000)
FROM    @Table1 t1
WHERE   t1.Col1 LIKE '%[0-9]%'
)
UPDATE  CteUpdate
SET     Col1    = LeftPart,
        Col2    = RightPart
OUTPUT  inserted.Col1, inserted.Col2;
```

Results (`Col1 & Col2` values after splitting) :

```
/*
Col1         Col2
------------ -------
dddddjh hdgh 045332 123
dddddjh hdgh 045332
gdggeg dgdfg 154123
gdggeg dgdfg 1
gdggeg dgdfg NULL
gdggeg       NULL
gdggeg       NULL
             NULL
             NULL
NULL         NULL
*/
```

Note: the splitting point is first digit computed using `PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', t1.Col1)`. If there is no digit within `x.Col1` column then `PATINDEX` returns `0` or `NULL` (if original source value is also `NULL`).

Answer (score 0):

Use `PARSENAME`!!!

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT REPLACE(columnname,' ','.') AS columnname
  FROM MyTable
)
SELECT PARSENAME(columnname,1) + ' ' + PARSENAME(columnname,2) AS columnname
,  PARSENAME(columnname,3) AS newcolumn
FROM cte
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([columnname] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('John Ede 045332')
,('Eva Neo 154123')
,('Alex Bob 1489')

Select  Col1 = left([columnname],len([columnname])-charindex(' ',reverse([columnname])+' '))
       ,Col2 = right([columnname],charindex(' ',reverse([columnname])+' ')-1)
from @YourTable
```

Returns

```
Col1         Col2
John Ede     045332
Eva Neo      154123
Alex Bob     1489
```